# Define a graph in an ontology

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, semantic-web

I have a knowledge base which includes multiple graphs. I want a way to formally define these graphs in my metadata layer. But I can't seem to find a standard way to do it. More specifically If I want to say `A` is a `class` I can use `rdfs:class`. But what if I want to have a collection that contains names of all of my graphs and I want to say these names are `named graphs`. I was thinking about it and all I could think of was to define a graph as a `rdf:bag` of `rdf:statement`. But I don't think this is a good one. Is there any existing vocabulary that I can use for this?

Comment: Related: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-service-description/#sd-availableGraphs

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the [DCAT Initiative](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-dcat/) might be worth having a look.

> Dataset Catalogue Vocabulary (DCAT) is a W3C-authored RDF vocabulary designed to facilitate interoperability between data catalogs published on the Web.

I am learning about this subject matter as well.  Apparently an Australian regulating body (for georesources) seems to have bundled their Graphs (concerning Geology the science, and Mining the Engineering discipline) with DCAT: [CGIVocPrez](https://cgi.vocabs.ga.gov.au/object?uri=http%3A//resource.geosciml.org/def/voc/&_profile=alt). You might look here for an application example. But I cannot tell how "good" it actually is.